# Add space between two divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a navbar with the two regions split with white space between. I've tried using `float:right` and `justify-content: space-between`, but I'm not sure why it is not doing anything. I would like for `site-header-right` to go on the right side and `site-header-navbar` to the left.

I did think of making margins between the two divs but that just seemed like an ugly fix, which may or may not cause responsiveness problems later. (If I'm wrong though about that, please tell me haha).

```css
.site-header-navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

nav ul li .sale {
  color: #a62120;
}

.site-header-right {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}

.small-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.search-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.site-header-right a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.site-navigation {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="site-header-masthead">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 navbar">
          <div class="menu-hamburger"></div>
          <div class="toast-logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpeg" width="110px"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="site-navigation">
            <nav class="site-header-navbar">
              <ul class="site-nav">
                <li><a href="https://us.toa.st/collections/women">Women</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://us.toa.st/collections/men">Men</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://us.toa.st/collections/house-home">House&Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://us.toa.st/collections/sale" class="sale">Sale</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://us.toa.st/pages/events">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://us.toa.st/blogs/magazine">Magazine</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://us.toa.st/pages/about-us">Our Approach</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="site-header-right">
              <div class="small-container">
                <button class="search-btn">Search</button>
                <a href="#" class="site-header-wishlist">
                  <span>Saved</span>
                  <span>(0)</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="site-header-account">Account</a>
                <a href="#" class="site-header-cart">
                  <span>Bag</span>
                  <span>(0)</span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `justify-content: space-between;` to your flex container (`.site-navigation`) to move the two child elements to the far left and right. And erase `margin: auto;` for the two flex items! All other offsets are due to margins (also default margins top and bottom), so you might want to reset these to 0.

```css
.site-header-navbar {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

nav ul li .sale {
  color: #a62120;
}

.site-header-right {
  display: inline-block;
}

.small-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.search-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.site-header-right a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.site-navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-header-masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 navbar">
        <div class="menu-hamburger"></div>
        <div class="toast-logo">
          <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpeg" width="110px"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="site-navigation">
          <nav class="site-header-navbar">
            <ul class="site-nav">
              <li><a href="https://us.toa.st/collections/women">Women</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://us.toa.st/collections/men">Men</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://us.toa.st/collections/house-home">House&Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://us.toa.st/collections/sale" class="sale">Sale</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://us.toa.st/pages/events">Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://us.toa.st/blogs/magazine">Magazine</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://us.toa.st/pages/about-us">Our Approach</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <div class="site-header-right">
            <div class="small-container">
              <button class="search-btn">Search</button>
              <a href="#" class="site-header-wishlist">
                <span>Saved</span>
                <span>(0)</span>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="site-header-account">Account</a>
              <a href="#" class="site-header-cart">
                <span>Bag</span>
                <span>(0)</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried space-between, but it didn't work. The two divs seem locked together

Comment: did you remove the `margin: auto` from `.site-header-navbar` and `.site-header-right`, as I wrote?

Comment: I made the .site-navigation width: 100%, and then space-between worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use **&nbsp** between your navbars

```
&nbsp
```